# Is this a good way to receive a message from a server?

Tags: c#

I am developing some software that uses a pretty ancient low-level TCP/IP protocol from (I think) the eighties. I can send messages to the server very reliably, but I am a little unsure about receiving them. I cannot predict when the server will send me a message, so I have this method in an infinite loop. GetNextMessage() blocks the thread until it receives a message, whereupon the message is acted upon, and the loop repeats.

Messages are sent at a rate of about maybe 5 or 6 a minute, and I can process them in less than a quarter of a second, so I'm not currently spinning off a new thread when I receive them.

This code fragment contains all the relevant symbols and the logic that I am unsure of:

```
    /// this is filled earlier in the program
    private Socket _socket;

    private const int BufferSize = 4096;

    /// <summary>
    /// This byte (hex 02) indicates the start of the message.
    /// </summary>
    private const byte RecordStart = 2;

    /// <summary>
    /// This byte (hex 03) indicates the end of the message.
    /// </summary>
    private const byte RecordEnd = 3;

    private string GetNextMessage()
    {
        byte[] bytesReceived = new byte[BufferSize];

        // ReSharper disable PossibleNullReferenceException
        _socket.Receive(bytesReceived);
        // ReSharper restore PossibleNullReferenceException

        if (_socket.Poll(1, SelectMode.SelectRead))
        {
            throw new SocketException((int)SocketError.ConnectionReset);
        }

        IEnumerable<byte> bytes = bytesReceived
            .Where(character => character != RecordStart)
            .TakeWhile(character => character != RecordEnd);

        return Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes.ToArray());
    }
```

My concerns:

1. I am not sure if _socket.Poll() is the correct way to determine if the socket has gone away. It most certainly works and is very necessary, but I'm sure I should be doing something else.
2. I once performed an operation that sent three messages immediately after each other, but I only appeared to receive two of them. It is possible that there is a bug in the product I am developing for (seems likely), but I am worried that the method I have chosen is somehow causing messages to be discarded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One thing I do with reading from sockets is separate receiving of the data from what the data contains.

Meaning, you may get your information in progressive chunks.....  so receive a chunk of data, then see if you have a complete "Message".  If not, wait for the next chunk of data.  When you have your full "Message"  then you can pass that on to whatever wants it.

In fact what I have done is abstract the idea of a streaming connection so I can interchange serial ports / tcp sockets / and any other streaming type connection.  Have something that receives from a connection, and then do interpreting.

Answer (score 1):

A: 1. Here's a better way to check if a socket has disconnected.

```
    bool SocketConnected(Socket s)
    {
        bool part1 = s.Poll(1000, SelectMode.SelectRead);
        bool part2 = (s.Available == 0);
        if (part1 & part2)
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    }
```